# Can not create google cloud DNS

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

Cloud DNS can no longer be created after I repeated, several times, Installing WordPress on the Google Cloud and Removing the Project.

A warning similar to the following appears.

The domain "mydomainatgoogledomain.com." (or its child domains) may be reserved or registered already, prohibited by policy, or there may be no DNS name server shards remaining for the name. For more information see https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#nameserver_limits.

Currently, only one Google wp installed project exists on my google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your already deleted project doesn't delete entire resources yet.

Wait a little longer until entire resources are all deleted.

Or Try undelete the project, remove manually all resources, then delete the project again.

Comment: He will need to undelete the project and then delete the DNS resources. Otherwise he will have to wait 30 days for the project to be recycled.

Answer (score 0):

I agree both answers.
Checking documentation[1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects),it says:
Warning: You can recover most resources if you restore a project within the 30-day period. Some services have delays in restoring and you might need to wait some time for services to be restored. Some resources, such as Cloud Storage resources, are deleted much sooner. These resources might not be fully recoverable even if you restore the project within the 30-day period. Billing accounts are immediately disconnected, and must be manually linked again after the project is restored.

Try to recover the project and delete the resources manually, then the domain should be available.